# How can I put border to the nodes in tikzpicture?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am writing my thesis defence presentation using beamer. My working code is as follows:

```
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND THEMES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\documentclass[aspectratio=169,xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usetheme{Simple}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{helvet,tikz,tikz-cd,pgf,makecell,smartdiagram,lmodern,ragged2e,array,caption,graphicx,booktabs,tabularx,subfig,xcolor,csquotes,epigraph,amsmath}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,backgrounds,fit,positioning,quotes,shapes}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} 

\captionsetup[figure]{labelformat=empty}
%\citationstyle{dcu}

%% Fix Vertical Alignment
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\small}m{#1}} 

% Add \hspace to arrow definition
\newcommand\bigleftArrow{\hspace{40pt}\color{green}\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{\scalebox{2.4}[3.6]{\ding{225}}}} 
\newcommand\bigrightArrow{\hspace{40pt}\color{green}\rotatebox[origin=c]{0}{\scalebox{2.4}[3.6]{\ding{225}}}}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, matrix, positioning, shapes, shapes.geometric, calc, intersections, decorations.pathreplacing,mindmap,trees}
\newcommand{\tikznode}[2]{\relax
    \ifmmode%
    \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base),inner sep=0pt] \node (#1) {$#2$};
    \else
    \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base),inner sep=0pt] \node (#1) {#2};%
    \fi}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% The title
\title[short title]{Simple Beamer Theme}
\subtitle{Subtitle}

\author[Pin-Yen] {Pin-Yen Huang}
\institute[NTU] % Your institution may be shorthand to save space
{
    % Your institution for the title page
    Department of Computer Science and Information Engineering \\
    National Taiwan University 
    \vskip 3pt
}
\date{\today} % Date, can be changed to a custom date


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PRESENTATION SLIDES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Introduction}
    \framesubtitle{Background and motivation}
    \tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, rounded corners, align=center, fill={rgb:orange,1;yellow,2;pink,5}, text width=2.2cm]
    \tikzstyle{block1} = [draw, rectangle, rounded corners, align=center, fill=orange!40, text width=2.5cm]
    \tikzstyle{block3} = [circle, draw, fill={rgb:orange,1;yellow,2;pink,5}, 
    text width=1cm, text centered, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=0.2pt]
    
    \begin{figure}[!h]
        \centering
        \resizebox{10cm}{6.5cm}{
            \begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
                %automaton
                \node [block] (automaton) {\textbf{Automaton}};
                \node [block1, below=of automaton, xshift=-0.5cm] (automaton2) {Automaton 2};
                \node [block1, left=of automaton2, xshift=0.7cm] (automaton1) {Automaton 2};
                \node [right=of automaton2, xshift=-0.9cm] (automaton3) {$\cdots$};
                \node [block1, right=of automaton3, xshift=-0.9cm] (automaton4) {Automaton $n$};
                
                %semigroup
                \node [block, right=of automaton, yshift=0.5cm, xshift=5cm] (semigroup) {\textbf{Semigroup}};
                \node[block1, below=of semigroup, xshift=-1.5cm] (semi1) {Group};
                \node[block1, right=of semi1, xshift=-0.5cm] (semi2) {Monoid};
                \node[block1, below=of semi1] (semi3) {Semigroup};
                \node[block1, below=of semi2] (semi4) {Semigroup};
                
                %primes
                \node[block, below=of automaton, yshift=-3.5cm, xshift=4cm] (positive) {\textbf{Positive integers}};
                \node[block3, below=of positive, xshift=0.5cm] (p3) {$p_3$};
                \node[block3, left=of p3, xshift=0.5cm] (p2) {$p_2$};
                \node[block3, left=of p2, xshift=0.5cm] (p1) {$p_1$};
                \node[right=of p3, xshift=-0.7cm] (dots) {$\cdots$};
                \node[block3, right=of dots, xshift=-0.7cm] (pn) {$p_n$};
                
                %lines
                \draw [line width=0.5pt] (automaton.south) -- (automaton1.north);
                \draw [line width=0.5pt] (automaton.south) -- (automaton2.north);
                \draw [line width=0.5pt] (automaton.south) -- (automaton4.north);
                
                \draw [line width=0.5pt] (semigroup.south) -- (semi1.north);
                \draw [line width=0.5pt] (semigroup.south) -- (semi2.north);
                \draw [line width=0.5pt] (semi1.south) -- (semi3.north);
                \draw [line width=0.5pt] (semi2.south) -- (semi4.north);
                
                \draw [line width=0.5pt] (positive.south) -- (p1.north);
                \draw [line width=0.5pt] (positive.south) -- (p2.north);
                \draw [line width=0.5pt] (positive.south) -- (p3.north);
                \draw [line width=0.5pt] (positive.south) -- (pn.north);
            \end{tikzpicture}
        }
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{References}
    % Beamer does not support BibTeX so references must be inserted manually as below
    \footnotesize{
        \begin{thebibliography}{99}
            \bibitem[Smith, 2012]{p1} John Smith (2012)
            \newblock Title of the publication
            \newblock \emph{Journal Name} 12(3), 45 -- 678.
        \end{thebibliography}
    }
\end{frame}

%------------------------------------------------

\begin{frame}
    \Huge{\centerline{The End}}
\end{frame}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

that produces a diagram as follows:

[image]

How can I add borders to the figure that looks like this one:

[image]

Please help.

Comment: Not related but you use in your code `tikzstyle` which is deprecated nowadays. You should use `tikzset` instead. And you define a new command `\tikznode` which exists now (named `\tikzmarknode`) into the `tikzmark` library. To answer your question, you can define those corners with the `fit` library, then draw between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's something, using `calc` and `fit` libraries. I deleted everything useless and only kept the tikzpicture, but it should work without any problem inside your beamer presentation.

[image: fit and calc to frame pictures]

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{helvet,tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows,backgrounds,fit,positioning,quotes,shapes}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PRESENTATION SLIDES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
\sffamily

    \tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, rounded corners, align=center, fill={rgb:orange,1;yellow,2;pink,5}, text width=2.2cm]
    \tikzstyle{block1} = [draw, rectangle, rounded corners, align=center, fill=orange!40, text width=2.5cm]
    \tikzstyle{block3} = [circle, draw, fill={rgb:orange,1;yellow,2;pink,5}, 
    text width=1cm, text centered, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=0.2pt]


        \resizebox{10cm}{6.5cm}{
            \begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
                %automaton
                \node [block] (automaton) {\textbf{Automaton}};
                \node [block1, below=of automaton, xshift=-0.5cm] (automaton2) {Automaton 2};
                \node [block1, left=of automaton2, xshift=0.7cm] (automaton1) {Automaton 1};
                \node [right=of automaton2, xshift=-0.9cm] (automaton3) {$\cdots$};
                \node [block1, right=of automaton3, xshift=-0.9cm] (automaton4) {Automaton $n$};
                
                %semigroup
                \node [block, right=of automaton, yshift=0.5cm, xshift=5cm] (semigroup) {\textbf{Semigroup}};
                \node[block1, below=of semigroup, xshift=-1.5cm] (semi1) {Group};
                \node[block1, right=of semi1, xshift=-0.5cm] (semi2) {Monoid};
                \node[block1, below=of semi1] (semi3) {Semigroup};
                \node[block1, below=of semi2] (semi4) {Semigroup};
                
                %primes
                \node[block, below=of automaton, yshift=-3.5cm, xshift=4cm] (positive) {\textbf{Positive integers}};
                \node[block3, below=of positive, xshift=0.5cm] (p3) {$p_3$};
                \node[block3, left=of p3, xshift=0.5cm] (p2) {$p_2$};
                \node[block3, left=of p2, xshift=0.5cm] (p1) {$p_1$};
                \node[right=of p3, xshift=-0.7cm] (dots) {$\cdots$};
                \node[block3, right=of dots, xshift=-0.7cm] (pn) {$p_n$};
                
                %lines
                \draw [line width=0.5pt] (automaton.south) -- (automaton1.north);
                \draw [line width=0.5pt] (automaton.south) -- (automaton2.north);
                \draw [line width=0.5pt] (automaton.south) -- (automaton4.north);
                
                \draw [line width=0.5pt] (semigroup.south) -- (semi1.north);
                \draw [line width=0.5pt] (semigroup.south) -- (semi2.north);
                \draw [line width=0.5pt] (semi1.south) -- (semi3.north);
                \draw [line width=0.5pt] (semi2.south) -- (semi4.north);
                
                \draw [line width=0.5pt] (positive.south) -- (p1.north);
                \draw [line width=0.5pt] (positive.south) -- (p2.north);
                \draw [line width=0.5pt] (positive.south) -- (p3.north);
                \draw [line width=0.5pt] (positive.south) -- (pn.north);
                
                \node[fit=(automaton)(automaton1)(automaton4),inner sep=10pt](automat){};
                \node[fit=(semigroup)(semi3)(semi4),inner sep=10pt](semi){};
                \node[fit=(positive)(p1)(pn),inner sep=10pt](p){};
                
                \draw[violet]   (semi.north east) |- (p.south east) -| (automat.south west) |- (semi.north east)
                                ($(semi.north west)!.5!(semi.north west-|automat.north east)$) |- ($(semi.south east)!.5!(semi.south east |- p.north east)$) -| (automat.north west); 
                
            \end{tikzpicture}
        }


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

Comment: How about `\draw (current boundingbox.north west) rectangle (current boundingbox.south east);`?

Comment: You're right. I was carried away with the `|-` syntax. Anyway, you have to draw the inner lines taking account of the distance between each part.